# C++ error message output format

Tags: c++, design-patterns

If I want to trigger an error in my interpreter I call this function:

```
Error( ErrorType type, ErrorSeverity severity, const char* msg, int line );
```

However, with that I can only output

```
Name error: Undefined variable in line 1
```

instead of

```
Name error: Undefined variable 'someVariableName' in line 1
```

I'm working entirely with strings (except for the error messages as they all are constant at the moment), so sprintf won't work.

- What is the best way to create an efficient error function that can output a constant message combined with a string that describes which object, e.g.: a non-existing variable, triggered the error?

Comment: What is `Error` function? Some code, please. Sample of using...

Comment: Error( ErrorType type, ErrorSeverity severity, const char* msg, int line );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is C++, so you can overload your function with an extra parameter to provide the variable name. I would then use a std::stringstream  to format the message. There is no need to worry about "efficiency" when reporting errors, as they should be rare and don't affect an application's overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

use a macro branched on your error function that build your message.

example:

```
#define ERROR(var, msg) error(0, 1, #var " -> " msg, __LINE__)
#define WARNING(var, msg) error(0, 2, #var " -> " msg, __LINE__)
```